# google storage bucket file link publicly accessible even though not public?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I was playing around with google bucket. The bucket is not public. The files are also not public.

After i upload the .csv file. I click on it and it shows the file with a loooong complicated url link in the browser in google chrome.

Now if i take that link and open in another browser like IE where no google account is logged in. I am able to get to the data . Is this a flaw ? Google team says that it is permissions issue. I tried it by removing all permissions but the file is still accessible.  Are you seeing the same issue with your buckets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumes the bucket name is `xtest` and the object name is `test.txt`.

That long complicated URL contains a signature that provides permissions to access the object.

If the URL looks very complicated and does not look like this, then it probably has a signature as part of the URL.

```
http://xtest.storage.googleapis.com/test.txt
```

OR

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/xtest/test.txt
```

If the URL does not contain a signature that allows anyone to access the bucket object, then the next steps are to figure out what permissions have been applied that allow anonymous access.

**Figure out what permissions are applied to the bucket and object.**

I prefer to use the CLI `gsutil` so that I have precise JSON describing all permissions.

There are two methods to grant access to buckets and objects. Bucket ACLs and Bucket IAM Policies.

**PART 1 - Bucket ACLs**

**Get the Bucket ACL.**

`gsutil acl get gs://xtest`

This will return a JSON response. If the bucket acl contains either of the following entries, your bucket is exposed.

```
[
  {
    "entity": "allUsers",
    "role": "READER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "allAuthenticatedUsers",
    "role": "READER"
  }
]
```

**Remove public permissions.**

The `allUsers` entity allows anyone the permissions specified by `role`.
The `allAuthenticatedUsers` entity allows anyone with a Google Account the permissions specified by `role`.

This command will remove `allUsers` from the bucket ACL.

```
gsutil acl ch -d allUsers gs:/xtest
```

This command will remove `allAuthenticatedUsers` from the bucket ACL.

```
gsutil acl ch -d allAuthenticatedUsers gs:/xtest
```

When changing ACLs on a bucket or file, it can take about a minute to take effect.

**Repeat the process for the object:**

`gsutil acl get gs://xtest/test.txt`

**Using similar commands to remove any public ACLs:**

`gsutil acl ch -d allUsers gs://xtest/test.txt`

`gsutil acl ch -d allAuthenticatedUsers gs://xtest/test.txt`

**Repeat verifying that public ACLs have been removed.**

`gsutil acl get gs://xtest`

`gsutil acl get gs://xtest/test.txt`

**Part 2 - Bucket IAM Policies**

**Get the Bucket IAM Policy.**

```
gsutil iam get gs://xtest
```

This will return a JSON response. If the bucket IAM policy contains either of the following entries, your bucket is exposed.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "allUsers"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "allAuthenticatedUsers"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.objectViewer"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "CBM="
}
```

**Remove public permissions.**

The allUsers entity allows anyone the permissions specified by role. The allAuthenticatedUsers entity allows anyone with a Google Account the permissions specified by role.

This command will remove allUsers from the bucket IAM policy.

```
gsutil iam ch -d allUsers gs://xtest
```

This command will remove allAuthenticatedUsers from the bucket IAM policy.

```
gsutil iam ch -d allAuthenticatedUsers gs://xtest
```

**Repeat the process for the object:**

`gsutil iam get gs://xtest/test.txt`

**Using similar commands to remove any public object IAM policies:**

`gsutil iam ch -d allUsers gs://xtest/test.txt`

`gsutil iam ch -d allAuthenticatedUsers gs://xtest/test.txt`

**Repeat verifying that public IAM policies have been removed.**

`gsutil iam get gs://xtest`

`gsutil iam get gs://xtest/test.txt`

Comment: The loooong compicated link is actually a temporary link and it expires in few min . But I am checking with google to see how we can restrict even further.

Comment: Let me know what you learn. I am writing articles on Google Cloud Authentication, credentials and access tokens. I plan like to dive into temporary object grants (URLs) also. Link: https://www.jhanley.com