# Removing allUsers default acl on Google Cloud Storage (GCS)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, access-control, gsutil

During experiments I accidentally add default read access for all users in one of bucket that shouldn't be public. I used the following command:

```
gsutil defacl ch -u allUsers:R gs://my-bucket
```

After realizing my mistakes, I try to delete the default read access using the following command:

```
gsutil defacl ch -d allUsers gs://my-bucket
```

However, when I checked, the deletion is not working! When I upload new file, it still give read access to public. When I check with:

```
gsutil defacl get gs://my-bucket
```

it still showing the read access permission for allUsers.

Is this a bug on gsutil function? currently I use gsutil version 4.34.

Is there any other way to change the default access for allUsers for google cloud storage buckets? If there is another ways, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: How are you checking that the file is still accessible? I tried to reproduce the issue and when using `gsutil defacl get gs://my-bucket` the output is the same before and after the changes to `allUsers` in the ACL. Also the newly uploaded files, are non-public for me.

Comment: Just forgot to add that you can change the ACL using the Console, API and the Client Libraries aswell. Check the documentation for specific ways on how to do it: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#changing-acls

Comment: @Maxim I also checked by uploading a new file, and they always have public read access (read access for allUsers). 

And currently my problem is not the ACL for existing file, but more on the default ACL for a new uploaded files. I can't find a way to change this on console, on the documentation you share, it also said:
`You cannot set default object ACLs using the GCP Console. Use gsutil instead.`

Anyways thanks for your comment :)

Comment: So when viewing the GCS bucket from the Cloud Console, it appears as 'Public' under 'Public access'? If so, could you tell me the output of `gsutil defacl get gs://my-bucket`? Make sure to remove all sensitive information beforehand if any. Also, do you get any warnings or errors during this process?

Comment: For another question I answered this with step-by step details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075168/8016720

Comment: @Maxim when i do `gsutil defacl get gs://my-bucket` I will get
`[
  {
    "entity": "allUsers",
    "role": "READER"
  }
]`
There are no error or warning..

Comment: @JohnHanley when I do `gsutil acl get gs://my-bucket` or `gsutil iam get gs://my-bucket` the result looks fine, there is no `allUsers` or `allAuthenticatedUsers`. My problem is more on `gsutil defacl get gs://my-bucket` (it will cause the new file to be public by default..., I need to manually change the acl for each new file now). And similar approach, using `gsutil defacl ch -d gs://my-bucket`, does not work.

Comment: @YosuaMichael So in short, `gsutil defacl ch -d allUsers gs://my-bucket` has no effect on the bucket without any output, and showing the same `get` output as before attempting to deletion?

Comment: @Maxim yes, that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've attempted to reproduce this issue several times to no avail. I'm afraid it's rather difficult to troubleshoot this situation without having access to the project's metadata and configuration; as this is something that is indeed needed at this point in order to figure out what may have gone wrong.

I'm a Google Cloud Support employee - my suggestion is to open a private issue on the Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164), stating your project number and the affected Cloud Storage bucket. Also, please make sure to include a link of this StackOverflow post as well.

Lastly, please let me know the issue ID or the link to the private issue once you create it, so I'm able to have a look at it as soon as possible.

**Edit:**

Resolution was to run the following gsutil [command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#defaultobjects), which sets the default ACL to the [project-private](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#defaultbuckets) ACL's default entries:

```
gsutil defacl set project-private gs://my-bucket
```

This issue happens when there’s only one entry in the ACL, making it impossible to delete it, even though it responds with everything being correctly updated.

Comment: Hi @Maxim, here is the private issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121998359 Thanks!

Comment: @YosuaMichael Thank you. I've left a comment on the private issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an individual object in a bucket which I had set to public. I was only able to delete the allUsers permission after I'd added a new permission to the object - even using the "project-private" command suggested didn't work.