# Unable to make gs:// file public to serve directly from Google Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to be able to serve image files directly from Google Storage. I'm following the [code suggestion from Google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/public_access#serving_files_directly_from_google_cloud_storage), but I'm still getting `Access Denied` and `Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access`. I'm running this in my Google App Engine project:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$storage = new StorageClient();
$storage->registerStreamWrapper();

$text = "Contained text: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n";

$options = ['gs' => ['acl' => 'public-read']];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$filepath = "gs://$project.appspot.com/public_file.txt";
file_put_contents($filepath, $text, 0, $context);

$publicurl = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl($filepath, false);
```

The file is being successfully written to Google Storage. I've looked at it via the Storage Browser in the Cloud Console.

But when I try to browse to it, I get `Access Denied`. What am I missing?

[image]

```
$ gsutil acl get gs://my-app-project.appspot.com/public_file.txt

[
  {
    "entity": "project-owners-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "team": "owners"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-editors-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "team": "editors"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-viewers-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "team": "viewers"
    },
    "role": "READER"
  },
  {
    "email": "my-app-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    "entity": "user-my-app-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    "role": "OWNER"
  }
]
```

Comment: I assume you're getting the error when accessing the object from the public URL. At a first glance, this could be due to the object's visibility not being correctly set as public. Could you please specify the link of the code sample you’re using? So perhaps I’m able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Maxim Here is the Google code sample: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/public_access#serving_files_directly_from_google_cloud_storage

Comment: Kenny, use `gsutil` to determine what permissions are set for your file. Change the following command to match your bucket and object path: `gsutil acl get gs://mybucket/myobject`. To make this object public read  `allUsers` needs to be specified in the acl policy. I have a feeling that `allUsers` is set but another bucket acl is overwriding this. The policy will contain this: 
{ 
| "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "allUsers"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    }
}

Comment: Here is a StackOverflow answer that I gave to figure out why an object is public. This may help you figure out why your object is not public: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075168/8016720

Comment: From running the code you provided, I had no issues in uploading the file and making it public. Nonetheless, I've managed to reproduce the issue by removing the `allUsers` entry from the ACL. As John said, the issue was that the file did not have `allUsers:R` entry set in the ACL, thus not allowing public access to the file. Run the following command to modify the ACL for the file: `gsutil acl ch -u allUsers:R gs://project.appspot.com/public_file.txt` Does this happen for every file you upload?

Comment: @Maxim Yes, it happens to every file that I upload. I need to be able to programmatically set files to public-read on demand when uploaded, and I can't rely on running gsutil by hand to get it work. I'll read through John Hanley's post about determining why my item isn't public. Do I need to make the ENTIRE bucket public, is that the problem?

Comment: @JohnHanley I've added what my gsutil says for the `public_file.txt`. I don't see any `allUsers` entries, even though I used the code above to set the file to `public-read`. Any ideas?

Comment: I tested your code and the “READER” role for “allUsers” is being set. So the file’s permissions are being overridden from another source (another part in the code, another app…). Try to create another bucket and write the file there. Then check with `gsutil acl get gs://my-new-bucket/public_file.txt` if there is an “allUsers” entity.

Comment: @TasosZG I created a new bucket and ran the code above (which is the entirety of the code affecting the file), and then did the `gsutil acl` but the file still doesn't have an `allUsers` permission role.

Comment: @TasosZG I even used `gsutil` to set the bucket to be public, but when I upload the file with the above code, it still doesn't show up as public. I can edit the permissions in the cloud console and then the image will serve properly, but when I upload a new file, it's still not public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure why the code above isn’t working to set the permissions to public, but here is a workaround.

If you are using a bucket that can be entirely public, then what you can do is set the default ACL on the bucket to be `public-read`, then whenever you create files in that bucket they will already be public.

Here is where I got the command from:
https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-storage

`gsutil defacl set public-read gs://[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]`